# Reading a dictionary from plist swift

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, plist

I'm trying to read some dictionaries from my plist, but unfortunately, my code doesn't see any dictionaries in the plist. Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BestScore</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>Coins</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>Anonim</string>
    <key>Store</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Shoes</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>Hats</key>
    <dict>
        <key>hatMagic2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>300</integer>
            <key>name_EN</key>
            <string> MAGIC HAT 2</string>
            <key>plusHealth</key>
            <integer>150</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>hatMagic1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>200</integer>
            <key>name_EN</key>
            <string>MAGIC HAT 1</string>
            <key>plusHealth</key>
            <integer>100</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>hatMagic</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Price</key>
            <integer>100</integer>
            <key>name_EN</key>
            <string>MAGIC HAT</string>
            <key>plusHealth</key>
            <integer>50</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And my code looks like that:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
var path = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("UserInfo.plist")  
var data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
println(data)
```

But swift doesn't see any dictionaries, output:

```
{
BestScore = "789.5";
Coins = 289;
UserName = Anonim;
}
```

So, how can i read those dictionaries from plist?

Comment: do you have extra `</dict>` at end or it just indent problem?

Comment: I set up a project with you plist in the bundle and it printed correctly with the dictionaries, so there must be something else going on. Maybe the file in the documents directory isn't exactly the same as the one you posted.

Comment: Did you add the plist file to your target membership ? You can confirm this by selecting the file and checking in "File inspector" pane on the right side of xcode.